# "To put into relation to each other"

Tags: phrases

I would like to ask if the phrase *to put into relation to each other* is correct English. I only found a few hits in the Internet and it looks like many of these sources were written in German.

I do not know how to describe it in my own words, but with *to put into relation to each other* I roughly mean *to compare something with each other*.

For example:

> In general, the purpose of this process is not to rate the absolute
>   quality of a result, but rather to put the qualities of several
>   results in relation to each other.

If any one of you speak German, by *to put into relation to each other* I mean *in Relation zueinander setzen*.

Thank you very much,

Alex

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. I actually want to use it in a mathematical context. So if I understand your answer correctly, it is grammatically correct to use it like in the sentence above?

Comment: most definitely it is correct.  In any other context outside of math, you'll probably get strange looks because it does sound odd.  But within mathematics it's perfectly good English.

Comment: thanks :-)

(To be precise, I will use it in the context of computer science. But it is a theoretical discussion and therefore similar to a mathematical one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To put into relation to each other" could just mean to set up a correlation between two sets of objects: "Apple, Orange, Banana" can be put into relation to "Car, Bus, Bike" as "Apple and Car, Orange and Bus, Banana and Bike". It'd be a strange to find outside of anything but a mathematics context.

Answer (score 0):

> comparative analysis

Is the general term for this kind of thing in English. Researching that term might yield more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the text you presented would be better rendered as:

> In general, the purpose of this process is not to rate the absolute quality of a result, but to juxtapose the qualities of several results.